# Why is Elastic Beanstalk missing Rolling deployment policies on new app creation?

Tags: web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using Elastic Beanstalk console, I'm trying to create a super basic Node.js environment using the preconfigured platform and sample application.

When I try to **configure more options** and then modify **Rolling updates and deployments**, I only have two options for *Deployment policy*. Why don't I have the option to select **Rolling** or **Rolling with additional batch**? What else would I need to do either within Elastic Beanstalk or in another service (resource) to be able to do this?

[image]

Region is N. California and IAM user is full admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Configuration present needs to be changed from the Low cost (Free Tier eligible) to either High availability or Custom Configuration. It would still be good to know how to change after the application has already been created using the Low cost preset.

[image]